# Why are the axes of the ellipse given by 2 times square root of the eigenvalues when trying to fit data using ellipse?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to fit my data points using an ellipse as given in the 2004 paper called "Principal Component Analysis for the Approximation of a Fruit as an Ellipse", using equation 25.

The length of the major and minor ellipse is given by 2√λ, where λ is the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the data. I'm wondering as to why it needs to be multiplied by 2.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that square root of the chi2inv of 86.664 (1.5 standard deviations) is equal to 2?

Comment: Please provide a relevant excerpt from the paper for context.

Comment: Here's the link to the paper:
https://www.academia.edu/17558162/Principal_component_analysis_for_the_approximation_of_an_image_as_an_ellipse